# Why the app stops after OnClick (), and if?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application, and a there is a part, where after clicking on a button 5 times, an activity  starts, and if the text is not being clicked in 10 minutes, then it goes back to the start (with the button, that you have to press 5 times).
The app exits every time, I get to this part, or just simply does not answer.
I am using an ImageView, a Button, and a TextView as you can see down below. I am getting this error, and for now, I don't know how to get over it.
I serached for some similar errors here, in stackoverflow, but what I found (more threads?) did not make any sence to me, since I am not that familiar with Android Studio.
If you could help me, I would be very thankful.

[...]

```
public void PreparingActivity() {
        Button Hbutton1 = findViewById(R.id.HiddenButton1);
        TextView start = findViewById(R.id.START);
        ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.Logo);
        if (5 == acceptance) {
            Hbutton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            logo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++) {
                    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            countison = true;
                        }
                    });
                    if (countison) {
                        break;
                    }
                    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                }
                if (countison) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!countison) {
                start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                acceptance = 0;
                TimerStarts();
            }
        }
    }
```

[...]
The error, that I get:

> CPU usage from 154450ms to 0ms ago (2023-02-12 10:35:30.281 to 2023-02-12 10:38:04.730):
> 1.8% 293/android.hardware.bluetooth@1.1-service.sim: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
> 0.9% 3817/com.example.szamlalo: 0% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 1755 minor
> 0.7% 303/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.3-service: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
> 0.6% 537/system_server: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 2140 minor
> 0.5% 362/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 5 minor
> 0.3% 311/android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
> 0.1% 732/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 408 minor
> 0% 291/android.hardware.audio.service.ranchu: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6 minor
> 0% 387/audioserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 12 minor [...]

There are like 30 more lines, like these, but I didn't see any use to paste them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the loop is executed in the ui thread, you can't do that, because rendering the application will freeze. You don't need loops to solve the problem, you can make things much simpler:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

public void PreparingActivity() {
    Button Hbutton1 = findViewById(R.id.HiddenButton1);
    TextView start = findViewById(R.id.START);
    ImageView logo = findViewById(R.id.Logo);
    if (5 == acceptance) {
        Hbutton1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                countison = true;
            }
        });

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!countison) {
                    // your back to the start code
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 10 * 60 * 1000);

        if (!countison) {
            start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            acceptance = 0;
            TimerStarts();
        }
    }
}
```

This code checks the value of the countison variable after 10 minutes and if it is false, it will run your code to navigate backwards.

**Explanation:**
TimerTask contains your code in the run method, which will execute the action backwards. It will be executed after 10 minutes have passed. You can change the time by changing the timer.schedule(timerTask, *min* * 60 * 1000)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it, as well as know how to solve it. I appriciate it